# What are "cx_core_ir_one_remote" and "ir_blaster_sniffing_supported" in Samsung TV/CX Core?

Tags: samsung, smart-tv

My Samsung TV/CX Core has these two options marked as true:

```
com.samsung/featureconfig/cx_core_ir_one_remote: true
com.samsung/featureconfig/ir_blaster_sniffing_supported: true
```

These options can be found by entering the hidden "Service menu", then select FMS -> FMS -> Factory App Menu -> Option -> Engineer Option -> CX CORE.

Can anyone tell me what they mean or what their purpose is?

Comment: Most likely both features are related to Samsung IR blaster like this https://www.samsung.com/levant/support/tv-audio-video/getting-connected-with-samsung-ir-blaster/